# Time Complexity for Python Zip Function

Tags: python, zip, time-complexity

`A = [1,2,3] B = ["a","c","d"]`

What is the time complexity for zip(A,B) and list(zip(A,B))?

Comment: linear to the size of A (and so B too).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The time complexity of `zip` is just a single function O(1) and wrapping it in `list` is linear O(n) of the smallest iterable supplied.

`zip` returns a generator object that while iterated over supplies the next value for all supplied iterables as a tuple until one is exhausted.

`list` consumes the iterablereturning a list of all it's results.